# How do I hide or disable the Clear Defaults dialog or notification?

Tags: default-applications

Everytime I am asked to associate and select a default app to open something with,
I always get this `Clear defaults` message:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot; click image for larger variant</sup>

Selecting `Always` (after selecting a default app) and clicking the `OK` button
will stop this message from appearing for that kind of association.
BUT, it will still appear for other types of associations.

Is there any way I can stop this notification from showing up?
(given that I already know how to `Clear defaults`)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the top answer to this question? If you don't want to accept it because you're looking for something else, you might [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop this notification from showing up, but you will need root and Xposed framework installed. So this solution is only for experienced Android user.

http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.disablecleardefaultsdialog